# Django, Django Rest Framwork, React and active directory

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, active-directory

### Context

For a client, I built a React app (app.client.com) using a Django app with the `django-rest-framework` (DRF) as a backend server under another domain (api.client.com). Right now the end users are logged in with `djoser` , meaning they swap their login credentials for a JSON web token.

The client uses Active Directory and right now he wants the end-users to login with Active Directory. If I had just created a Django app I could use [`django-microsoft-auth`](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). If i just created a React app but didn't need the DRF I could use [Auth0.com](https://auth0.com/authenticate/react/active-directory/) library

### Question

How can I let the user's log-in with their Microsoft account and at the same time use the same *logged in-state/credentials/access token* to authenticate requests at the Django (DRF) backend. Can I pass the access token from the frontend to the backend and use it to query the profile of the user for example?

[I found a similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57769803/django-microsoft-authentication-and-rest-framwork) However, it is unclear and not answered yet.

Answer (score 1):

have a look here if you consider auth0 :

https://auth0.com/authenticate/react/microsoft-account/

also, consider this approach if the client is working on Azure

[image: React Microsoft Auth]

using this npm module [react-azure-adb2c](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In your overview the browser will be the React app, or the React app nested within in the Django app on the same domain? Right now they are seperated.

So `react-azure-adb2c` will help me authenticate in the react app. But is there an easy way (framework) to register an user in the Django app at the same time? Or should i create a script in the react app to call the user register endpoint from Djoser myself. And furthermore how can i use the authenticated state in React to authenticate to the Django app safely. An e-mailadres or AD user_id can be spoofed easily.

Comment: in the callback of a successful authentication, send all the information to the back-end and create a record for that user, no need for django-microsoft-auth

Comment: Thnx! And what about authentication/log in? How can the Django backend know if it is really you?

Comment: @Florian Were you able to achieve this? If yes can you please share any docs or sample code